# If-else statement in .map loop in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Instagram clone:

I want to check if I follow my follower then display `<button>unfollow</button>` or if not display `<button>follow</button>`

```
var IfollowAndHeFollowMe;

myfollowers.map(follower => {
     return(
       <div>
          <div>{follower.userName}</div>
          { IfollowAndHeFollowMe = 
            myfollowings.filter((following) => following.userName == follower.userName)
          }


          // this doesn't work

         { IfollowAndHeFollowMe.length > 0 ? return( <button>unfollow</button>): return(<button>follow</button>) }


         // and this also doesn't work

         { return IfollowAndHeFollowMe.length > 0 ? <button>unfollow</button> : <button>follow</button>}


       </div>
    )
})
```

//https://instagram-app-clone.netlify.app/  --- just for phone ---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSX Code inside `{}` should be written as statements.

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

```js
const followers = ['John', 'Hanna'];

function RenderMap() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {followers.map(follower => (
                <div>
                    <span>{follower}</span>
                    {followers.length > 0 ? (
                        <button>unfollow</button>
                    ) : (
                        <button>follow</button>
                    )}
                </div>
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: without return??

Comment: Yes, this is how Javascript Ternary operators works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userName, name, profImg, posts}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: {
IfollowAndHeFollowMe = myfollowings.filter(following => following.userName == follower.userName)
}

Comment: and this is bad , can y help me?

Comment: Sure, lets try to open a chat and go there.

Comment: {
IfollowAndHeFollowMe = myfollowings.filter(following => following.userName == follower.userName)
}                                                                                                                                                      this will add object in IfollowAndHeFollowMe  but i want just to add following.userName

Comment: At certain number of comments chat option is opening. Lets try it.

Comment: Still wrining :)

Comment: I dont know yet how to launch a chat without messages limit.

Comment: i am bored  

Comment: chat is still not activating... weird

Comment: User15170586 has only 3 reputation, not yet enough to chat
Add a comment

Comment: OK then lets do it old way, update your code and show me how you are trying to render `myfollowers.map`

Comment: is that me or y?

Comment: i dont have reputation?

Comment: Yes, it seems like it.

Comment: OK then, wait few seconds I'll update my answer with a working version of component that renders a `.map`

Comment: i have second acc on stackover flow because i ask too much hahaha can we go tthare because that have ruputation i think

Comment: i answer you on one question from second acc

Comment: lets go there?.

Comment: i have following and people who i follow i eant to chack if i follow them than it will be button with follow text but if i dont follow them it will display button with unfollow text

Comment: i posted  answer on this question look real code

Comment: Also you can replace the condition by <button>{this followers.length ? "unfollow": "follow"}</button>

Comment: Hi bro, i need help if you can go again on teamviewer with me, to help me REACT APP...

Answer (score 0):

// now dont have errors but its allways display button with follow text

```
{Data[2][0].followers.map(follower => {
                idFollowers++;

                return (

                    <div className="follower" id={idFollowers}  >
                        <img src={follower.profilna} className="profilnaFollower" alt="" />

                        <div className="userInfoFollower">
                            <h3>{follower.userName}</h3>
                            <p>{follower.name}</p>
                        </div>

                        {dbFollow = Object.entries(Data[2][0].following).filter(following => following.userName == follower.userName)}
                        {dbFollow.length > 0 ? (<button>unfoldasdaslow</button>) : (<button>fodsadsllow</button>)}
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
```

Comment: Seems to be looking right, what is the error?

Comment: its cant dbFollow  be object because following1 is object. must be array or string , it will set following1 with .filter() but i want to dbFollow be following1.userName not object

Comment: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userName, name, profilna, posts}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: If you get this error you shared above: `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userName, name, profImg, posts}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` Then the problem is that you are using Array methods over an Object.

Comment: the problem is here:                                                                             
                                                 {dbFollow = following.filter(following1 => following1.userName == follower.userName

Comment: if `following` is an object, you first have to convert it to an Array like this: `Object.entries(following)` this will convert object into array with pairs of keyname and value.

Comment: then you can loop over that array with filter: `Object.entries(following).filter((following) => following[1].userName == 'username')`

Comment: Object.entries() returs array of arrays, this why to get value you have to extract it with index `following[1]`

Comment: can you `console.log(Data[2][0].following)` to see what to expect in its value?

Comment: if y have teamviewer my id : 516 465 870

Comment: do `console.log(Data[2][0].following)`

Comment: got launged teamviewer need password

Comment: 516 465 870   pass: 9nnv86

Comment: I have called you